# How can I change the strings of a UIPickerView from another UIPickerview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uipickerview

I have two `UIPickerview`, `pickerView1` and `pickerView2` in my view controller.

What I want to achieve here is when I select a string from my `pickerView1`, it automatically changes the strings for the `pickerView2`.

I created a section 3 because there was a lot of strings, ideally I want this all in section 1, as I currently have my code set to 3 picker views but I only want two picker views.

Here is an example.

Pickerview1 contains "a","b","c","d".

If "a" is selected, the `pickerView2` would show specific strings for that to choose from, if I choose "b" then the strings for "a" would not show but the strings for "b" would show separately.

In section 2 I want each of those fields to correspond with the sub strings that are defined in section 1 and section 3, this then populates the second UIpickerview, so every time i select a string in the first picker view the second uipickerview generates the specific strings for that.

Here is my code:

```
//PickerView Category IBOutlets

    @IBOutlet var pickerView1: UIPickerView! = UIPickerView()
    @IBOutlet var pickerView2: UIPickerView! = UIPickerView()
    @IBOutlet var pickerView3: UIPickerView! = UIPickerView()
    @IBOutlet var textField1: UITextField! = UITextField()
    @IBOutlet var textField2: UITextField! = UITextField()
    @IBOutlet var textField3: UITextField! = UITextField()

    var SECTION2 = ["Select", "Criminal Activity", "Begging","Harassment", "Criminal Damage", "Disruption Of Service", "Drunken Behaviour","Fare Evasion", "Feet on Seats", "Hate Crime", "Inappropriate Sexual Behaviour", "Litter", "Missile Throwing", "Noise","Rowdy Behaviour", "Smoking Tobacco", "Drugs", "Threats/abuse/intimidation towards Staff", "Threats/abuse/intimdation towards Passengers" ]

    var SECTION1 = ["Select", "*>>>Criminal Activity<<<*", "Assault", "Arson", "Trespass", "Spitting", "*>>>Begging<<<*", "On Board", "Off Board", "*>>>Harassment<<<*", "Stalking", "On Board", "At Stop/Station", "Bullying", "*>>>Criminal Damage<<<*", "Damage to Exterior", "Damage to Interior", "Glass Breakage","Grafitti", "Window Etching", "*>>>Disruption Of Service<<<*", "Interfering with the engine", "Opening emergency exits", "Pressing emergency stop/handles", "Throwing debris on to the line/track", "*>>>Drunken Behaviour<<<*", "Drinking on the mode of transport", "Drinking in the station/stop", "Aggressive Drunks", "*>>>Fare Evasion<<<*", "Fraudulent Pass", "None payment of fare", "*>>>Feet on Seats<<<*", "Purposeful Obstruction" ]

    var SECTION3 = ["Select", "*>>>Hate Crime<<<*", "Disability", "Ethnicity", "Gender", "Race","Religion", "Sexual Orientation", "*>>>Litter<<<*", "On Board", "At station/stop", "*>>>Missile Throwing<<<*", "Stone Throwing", "Throwing Objects", "*>>>Noise<<<*", "Inappropriate Musical Content", "Loud Music", "*>>>Rowdy Behaviour<<<*", "School Children", "Shouting/Swearing", "Within Shelter", "Within Station/Stop"," Groups/Gangs", "*>>>Smoking Tobacco<<<*", "On Board", "At station/stop", "*>>>Drugs<<<*", "Smoking Drugs", "Drug Paraphernalia", "Drug Taking", "Drug Dealing", "*>>>Threats/abuse/intimidation towards Staff<<<*", "On Board", "At station/stop", "*>>>Threats/abuse/intimidation towards Passengers<<<*", "On Board", "At station/stop" ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var Viewcontroller: () =
        pickerView1 = UIPickerView()
        pickerView2 = UIPickerView()
        pickerView3 = UIPickerView()
        pickerView1.delegate = self
        pickerView2.delegate = self
        pickerView3.delegate = self

        self.textField1.inputView = self.pickerView1;
        self.textField2.inputView = self.pickerView2;
        self.textField3.inputView = self.pickerView3;

        pickerView1.tag = 0
        pickerView2.tag = 1
        pickerView3.tag = 2

        textField1.inputView = pickerView1
        textField2.inputView = pickerView2
        textField3.inputView = pickerView3
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int  {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

        if pickerView.tag == 0 {
            return SECTION1.count
        } else if pickerView.tag == 1 {
            return SECTION2.count
        } else if pickerView.tag == 2 {
            return SECTION3.count
        }
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {

        if pickerView.tag == 0 {
            return SECTION1[row]
        } else if pickerView.tag == 1 {
            return SECTION2[row]
        } else if pickerView.tag == 2 {
            return SECTION3[row]
        }
        return ""
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)  {

        if pickerView.tag == 0 {
            textField1.text = SECTION1[row]
        } else if pickerView.tag == 1 {
            textField2.text = SECTION2[row]
        } else if pickerView.tag == 2 {
            textField3.text = SECTION3[row]
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the global variables

```
var data1:NSMutableArray=["Apple","Mango","Banana"]
    var data2:NSMutableArray=[["greenApple","whiteApple","yellowApple"],["greenMango","whiteMango","yelloMango"],["greenBanana","whiteBanana","yellowBanana"]]
    var data3:NSArray = []
```

Set the tags for pickerViews - pickerView1 (say 1) and pickerView2 (say 2).

```
     override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
      pickerView1.tag=1;
            pickerView2.tag=2;
data3=["greenApple","whiteApple","yellowApple"] //initialise the array with the data
     }
```

set the title in delegate method

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    if pickerView.tag==1 {
    return data1[row] as! String
    }
    else {
        return data3[row] as! String
    }

}
```

In selection delegate if the picker one is selected then assign the data3 with the required data based on pickerView1 selection and reload the pickerView2

```
 func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView,
    didSelectRow row: Int,
    inComponent component: Int)
{

     if pickerView.tag==1 {
        data3=data2[row] as! NSArray
        pickerView2.reloadAllComponents() // reload pickerview2
    }

}
```

Comment: I have tried the code above, however I am still running into errors, could you provide me with an example for this code written in "ViewController.swift" I would appreciate it thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement all the required methods of UIPickerViewDataSource and UIPickerViewDelegate, if you want to conform to these protocols.

and try this code for ViewController.swift

import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet var pickerView1: UIPickerView! = UIPickerView()
@IBOutlet var pickerView2: UIPickerView! = UIPickerView()
@IBOutlet var textField1: UITextField! = UITextField()
@IBOutlet var textField2: UITextField! = UITextField()

var data1:NSMutableArray=["Apple","Mango","Banana"]
var data2:NSMutableArray=[["greenApple","whiteApple","yellowApple"],["greenMango","whiteMango","yelloMango"],["greenBanana","whiteBanana","yellowBanana"]]
var data3:NSArray = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    pickerView1.tag=1;
    pickerView2.tag=2;
    data3=["greenApple","whiteApple","yellowApple"] //initialise the array with the data

    textField1.text = data1[0] as! String
    textField2.text = data3[0] as! String

}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int  {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return 3;
}
```

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {

```
if pickerView.tag==1 {
    return data1[row] as! String
}
else {
    return data3[row] as! String
}
```

}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
{

```
if pickerView.tag==1 {
    data3=data2[row] as! NSArray
    pickerView2.reloadAllComponents() // reload pickerview2
}

 if pickerView.tag==1 {
textField1.text = data1[row] as! String
 }else{
textField2.text = data3[row] as! String
}
```

}

```
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Comment: I added some additional code to get this to work, the problem that I have now is that "Apple" and "greenApple" appear in the textfields when I launch the app before clicking on the textfields to initialise the picker view. Also how do I add additional options in the first pickerview and second pickerview?